# C++: STL: vector: remove: destructor calls

Tags: c++, vector, destructor, std

The code is following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

struct A {
  A(int i = -1): i_(i) {
    wcout << "Constructor: i = " << i_ << endl;
  }
  A(A const &a) {
    wcout << "Copy constructor: i = " << i_ << " a.i = " << a.i_ << endl;
    *this = a;
  }
  ~A() { wcout << "Destructor: i = " << i_ << endl; }
  A &operator=(A const& a) {
    wcout << "Copy assignment operator: i = " << i_ << " a.i = " << a.i_ << endl;
    i_ = a.i_;
    return *this;
  }
  bool operator==(A const& rhs) { return i_ == rhs.i_; }
  int get() { return i_; }
private:
  int i_;
};

int wmain() {
  A a[] = {1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 5};
  vector<A> v(a, a + sizeof a/sizeof a[0]);
  wcout << "==== Just before remove ====" << endl;
 remove(v.begin(), v.end(), 2);
  wcout << "==== Just after remove ====" << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
==== Just before remove ====
Constructor: i = 2
Destructor: i = 2
Constructor: i = 2
Destructor: i = 2
Constructor: i = 2
Destructor: i = 2
Copy assignment operator: i = 2 a.i = 3
Constructor: i = 2
Destructor: i = 2
Constructor: i = 2
Destructor: i = 2
Copy assignment operator: i = 3 a.i = 4
Constructor: i = 2
Destructor: i = 2
Copy assignment operator: i = 2 a.i = 5
==== Just after remove ====
```

The question is: why destructor is called 6 times while remove() was running? I need this mess to be clarified.

NOTE: execute this code on your system, please, before answering.
NOTE: MSVCPP 11

Comment: Your output does not match the code. Where do the numbers come from?

Comment: If you log the value of `i_` in the destructor, it will be obvious. Hint: What types does your `operator==` compare?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> The question is: why destructor is called 6 times while remove() was
>   running?

In summary, the destructor calls have to do with the `2` getting implicitly converted to `A` by `remove()`. Every time the result of such an implicit conversion goes out of scope, `A`'s destructor gets called.

The reason for those implicit conversions is that `remove()` needs to compare every element of `a` to `2`. The only way to do this is by calling `A::operator==(const A&)`:

```
  bool operator==(A const& rhs) { ... }
```

Since `rhs` is of type `const A&`, the compiler:

1. calls `A(int)` to convert the `2` to an `A`;
2. calls `operator==(const A&)`;
3. calls `A::~A()` to destroy the temporary.

The latter are the destructor calls that you're seeing.

If you were to add the following comparison operator to `A`, you'll see those destructor calls disappear:

```
  bool operator==(int rhs) { return i_ == rhs; }
```

Alternatively, if you were to call `remove()` like so, you'll see all bar one destructor calls disappear:

```
remove( v.begin(), v.end(), A(2) );
```

Finally, if you were to make `A::A(int)` `explicit`, the compiler would not allow you to call `remove()` with `2` as the last argument (you'd have to call it with `A(2)`).

Comment: Indeed - for further clarity, OP could write constructor, copy constructor and assignment and make those log as well, to see how many temporaries are being created.

Comment: @DaddyM Now write `remove(v.begin(), v.end(), A(2))` instead and see what happens. Just remember that `remove` is a template that doesn't `take an `A` but anything you give it (in this case an `int`).

Comment: The explanation is partly wrong. `remove` takes 2 as `int` and constructs a temporary for each equality check. `std::remove` should not pass the object to compare against around by value.

Comment: @visitor: I've edited the answer 7 minutes ago to address this. I think you might be looking at an old, cached version.

Comment: @visitor: I've just rewritten the whole answer to hopefully make it clearer. (The edit might take a little while to propagate...)

Comment: +1 for the psychic powers to actually understand the question (and the right answer).

Answer (score 3):

> The question is: why destructor is called 6 times while remove() was
>   running?

Because `std::remove` just reorders the elements, but doesn't remove anything from the vector. In the process of reordering, some elements are copy-constructed.

---

Next code shows in details what happens :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

struct A {
  A(int i = -1): i_(i) {cout << "I was created" << i_ << endl;}
  ~A() {
    cout << "I was destroyed" << i_ << endl;
  }
  A(const A& o):i_(o.i_)
  {
    cout << "I was copied" << i_ << endl;
  }
  A& operator=(const A& o)
  {
    i_=o.i_;
    cout << "I was assigned" << i_ << endl;
    return *this;
  }
  int get() { return i_; }
  bool operator==(A const& rhs) { return i_ == rhs.i_; }
private:
  int i_;
};

int main() {
std::cout<<"start"<<std::endl;
  A a[] = {1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 5};

  std::cout<<"creating"<<std::endl;
  vector<A> v(a, a + sizeof a/sizeof a[0]);
  std::cout<<"removing"<<std::endl;
  remove( v.begin(), v.end(), 2 );
  std::cout<<"end"<<std::endl;
}
```

The `remove` is placing "removed" elements at the end of the vector.

Comment: all of the elements that destructed 6 times are "2"s

Answer (score 2):

`std::remove` is declared as

```
 template<typename ForwardIterator, typename Tp>
 ForwardIterator remove(ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last,
   const Tp& value);
```

In your usage, the third argument (2) is deduced as `int`. Because an `int` variable is not directly comparable against an `A` object, first a temporary has to be constructed for every

```
if (*it == value) ...
```

At the end of the comparison, the temporary is destroyed.

(All in all, you are having a hidden performance problem, resulting from having non-explicit single-argument, a.k.a. conversion constructor.)

Answer (score 1):

Well it's quite simple really; you only need to understand what `std::remove` does and how it does it. Hint: it does *not* remove elements from the vector. It moves then around instead, to the back of your collection. Moving an element in vector involves destroying original element. So this is where (part of) your destructor calls is coming from.

The other part is coming from temporary objects - since you passed an `int` (and not an instance of `struct A`) as a last parameter to `std::remove`, an instance of A has to be constructed for the purpose of comparison. If you want to force a little more discipline to your code, try to make it a habit to prefix one-parameter constructors with keyword `explicit`. It's very efficient at banishing such temporary objects. You will then have to create comparison object explicitly:

```
remove(v.begin(), v.end(), A(2));
```

Comment: Actually, the behavior of `std::remove` is unspecified as to the state in which it leaves the items past the new end. They are in a destroyable state, but no more is guaranted. In practice, it leaves the implementation free of "moving" or "swapping" them, or just copying from them and leaving them as is.

Comment: I guess you must be referring to this point in ISO 14882-2011 "Note: each element in the range [ret,last), where ret is the returned value, has a valid but unspecified state, because the algorithms can eliminate elements ...". It only means these objects do not satisfy any *specific* preconditions. Which makes them perfectly valid for any operations with *no* preconditions, not just destruction. Besides, it's irrelevant. Objects which were originally before ret and which have been "removed", must have been also destroyed. That was my point.

Comment: In part, the end of the citation is also important: *because the algorithms can eliminate elements by **swapping with** or moving from elements that were originally in that range*. It is unspecified whether the "removed" elements are destroyed or just exchanged with the "past-the-new-end" elements; with a swapping strategy, no destructor is invoked at all.

Comment: I will remove my answer; you are correct . Basically we don't know whether the algo is doing assignment, swap or something else. It *might* indirectly call destuctors but we dont know for sure